# Replace multiple switch case when checking for multiple integer ranges

Tags: javascript

I would like to simplify this code by removing all those switch case with (which make this look very bulky and I would like to condense this if at all possible), a single function and/or everything that could be used to remove those if recurrencies.

This is my code:

```
  function hemoglobine() {

hemoglobineInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let hemoglobineContainerValue = document.querySelector('#hemoglobina').value;
  switch(true) {
    case (ageGroup === 0 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 2 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 6.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AST';
      break;
      
    case (ageGroup === 0 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 6.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 7.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AS';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 0 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 7.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 11.4)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AM';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 0 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 11.4 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 13.4)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 0 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 13.4 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 19.8)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'HN';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 0 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 19.8)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'PL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 1 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 2 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 6.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AST';
      break;
        
    case (ageGroup === 1 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 6.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 7.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AS';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 1 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 7.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 9.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AM';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 1 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 9.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 10.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 1 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 10.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 13)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'HN';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 1 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 13)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'PL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 2 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 2 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 6.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AST';
      break;
        
    case (ageGroup === 2 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 6.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 7.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AS';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 2 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 7.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 9.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AM';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 2 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 9.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 11.4)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 2 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 11.4 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 15)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'HN';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 2 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 15)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'PL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 3 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 2 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 6.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AST';
      break;
        
    case (ageGroup === 3 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 6.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 7.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AS';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 3 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 7.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 10.4)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AM';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 3 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 10.4 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 12.4)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 3 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 12.4 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 16)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'HN';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 3 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 16)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'PL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 4 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 2 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 6.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AST';
      break;
        
    case (ageGroup === 4 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 6.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 7.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AS';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 4 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 7.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 9.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AM';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 4 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 9.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 11.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 4 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 11.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 16)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'HN';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 4 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 16)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'PL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 5 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 2 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 6.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AST';
      break;
        
    case (ageGroup === 5 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 6.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 7.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AS';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 5 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 7.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 10.4)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AM';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 5 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 10.4 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 12.9)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'AL';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 5 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 12.9 && hemoglobineContainerValue <= 18)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'HN';
      break;

    case (ageGroup === 5 && (hemoglobineContainerValue > 18)):
      hemoglobineValue = 'PL';
      break;

    default:
      hemoglobineValue = 'NONE';
  }    
});  
}
```

I've thought that their might be a way to make a dictionary by assigning key/value objects, but I'm not sure how to do this correctly. All hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make an array indexed by `ageGroup`, whose values are objects containing the `hemoglobineValue` and its associated lower threshold for that age group, you can iterate through the object's entries to `.find` the first matching entry:

```
const hValues = [
    // Age group 0:
    {
        AST: 6.9,
        AS: 7.9,
        AM: 11.4,
        AL: 13.4,
        HN: 19.8,
        PL: 100
    },
    // Age group 1:
    {
        AST: 6.9,
        AS: 7.9,
        AM: 9.9,
        AL: 10.9,
        HN: 13,
        PL: 100
    }
    // etc
]
function hemoglobine() {
    hemoglobineInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
        const input = Number(document.querySelector('#hemoglobina').value);
        const entry = Object.entries(hValues[ageGroup])
            .find(([, threshold]) => input <= threshold);
        const hemoglobineContainerValue = entry[0];
    });
}
```

You could also use an array of arrays instead of an array of objects in `hValues` to make things more concise, and have a separate array containing the `hemoglobineValue` strings, but IMO that data structure would be a bit harder to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

I do that...

```js
const agArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]    
const hvArr = 
    [ { hv_min:   2,   hv_max: 6.9,      res: 'AST' }
    , { hv_min:   6.9, hv_max: 7.9,      res: 'AS'  }
    , { hv_min:   7.9, hv_max: 10.4,     res: 'AM'  }
    , { hv_min:  10.4, hv_max: 12.9,     res: 'AL'  }
    , { hv_min:  12.9, hv_max: 18,       res: 'HN'  }
    , { hv_min:  18,   hv_max: Infinity, res: 'PL'  }
    ]

function get_hgv(ageGroup, hemoglobineContainerValue)
  {
  return !agArr.includes(ageGroup)
         ? 'NONE'
         : hvArr.find(x => hemoglobineContainerValue > x.hv_min 
                        && hemoglobineContainerValue <= x.hv_max
                     )?.res ?? 'NONE';
  }

console.log ('4,8  ->', get_hgv(4,8)  ) // AM
console.log ('4,12 ->', get_hgv(4,12) ) // AL
console.log ('4,0  ->', get_hgv(4,0)  ) // NONE
console.log ('9,8  ->', get_hgv(9,8)  ) // NONE
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```